# Como almacenar un array nulo?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un array que se genera al elegir items de un select multiple. En el proceso de grabación de datos hago esto:

```
if (isset($_POST['temas_event'])) {
   $temas_event = json_encode($_POST['temas_event']);
} else {
   $temas_event = ['0'];
}
```

Lo que he notado es que si bien en la base esta definido como valor por defecto "NULL" hay veces que si no selecciono nada en el select multiple, en la base de datos me graba la palabra "Array" con los consecuentes problemas que me genera al momento de leer los registros...  es decir que mi definicion del registro la ignora o esta mal definida.
Que me sugieren que puedo hacer ?

El proceso de grabación lo realizo como:

```
$conexion = new Conexion();
        $stmt = $conexion -> prepare("UPDATE usuarios_full SET nombre_event = :nombre_event, dom_event = :dom_event, lat_event = :lat_event, lng_event = :lng_event, web_event = :web_event, tel_event = :tel_event, alcance_event = :alcance_event, temas_event = :temas_event, cert_event = :cert_event, event_pagos = :event_pagos WHERE idusuario = :valor");

        $stmt->bindValue(":valor", $idusuario);

        $stmt->bindValue(":nombre_event", $nombre_event);
        $stmt->bindValue(":dom_event", $dom_event);
        $stmt->bindValue(":lat_event", $lat_event);
        $stmt->bindValue(":lng_event", $lng_event);
        $stmt->bindValue(":web_event", $web_event);
        $stmt->bindValue(":tel_event", $tel_event);
        $stmt->bindValue(":alcance_event", $alcance_event); (*******)
        $stmt->bindValue(":temas_event", $temas_event);   (*******)
        $stmt->bindValue(":cert_event", $cert_event);
        $stmt->bindValue(":event_pagos", $event_pagos);
        $stmt->execute();

        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            $resultado = 1;
        } else {
            $resultado = NULL;
        }
```

donde (*******) son arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el proceso de *grabación*, si la variable no esta seteada, podrías inicializarla como `array()`.

Así por ejemplo:

```
$valor = isset($_POST['temas_event'])? $_POST['temas_event'] : array();
$temas_event = json_encode($valor);
```

Por otro lado, la palabra `Array`, aparece porque en el `else` de tu lógica esta creando un arreglo y no lo estas encodeando (*eg: No le estas haciendo `json_encode`*)

### UPDATE

Como quieres guardar `null` o un `string`, entonces deberías hacerlo así:

```
$valor = isset($_POST['temas_event'])? json_encode($_POST['temas_event']) : null;
$temas_event = $valor;
```

Debido a que estas usando `PDO` y necesitas guardar `NULL` o un `string`, es necesario que a la hora de *"bindear"* el valor de la variable `$temas_event`, indiques distintos tipos de dato según el valor.

Así por ejemplo:

```
// ....
$type = $temas_event === null ? PDO::PARAM_INT : PDO::PARAM_STR;
$stmt->bindValue(":temas_event", $temas_event, $type);
// ....
```

**PD**: Podrías usar `PDO::PARAM_NULL` para el caso en que `$temas_event === null`, pero [se comenta que en algunos entornos `PDO::PARAM_NULL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391777/how-do-i-insert-null-values-using-pdo), no funciona correctamente

Comment: ah !!! podría hacer un json_encode ("0")

Comment: me interesaria almacenar nulo...

Comment: ahi lo añado a la descripcion del problema

Comment: me funcionó almacentando json_encode(array())

Comment: no dejalos los cambios, los estaba leyendo me parece muy interesante...

Comment: @MNibor, he vuelto a actualizar mi respuesta para dejarla un poco mas completa.